# How can I generate the table in Looker Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have this data in looker studio. This data is huge not limited to what I have represented. It is coming through API from Google Search Console.

| Address | Queries | Click | Impression | CTR | Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcdomain.com/abc-keyword | abc | 15 | 700 | 2.14% | 10.51 |
|  | keyword | 7 | 300 | 2.33% | 10.22 |
|  | abc 2 | 2 | 100 | 2.00% | 20.77 |
|  | abc 3 | 3 | 100 | 3.00% | 19.83 |
|  | abc new | 0 | 50 | 0.00% | 50.78 |
|  | abc coming | 0 | 30 | 0.00% | 65.87 |
|  | abc sleep | 0 | 12 | 0.00% | 75.63 |
| abcdomain.com/kite-flying | kite | 20 | 800 | 2.50% | 11.51 |
|  | kite flying | 0 | 0 | 0.00% | 11.22 |
|  | kite today | 0 | 250 | 0.00% | 40.78 |
|  | kite weather | 0 | 67 | 0.00% | 15.87 |
|  | kite colours | 0 | 9 | 0.00% | 15.63 |

What I want in the table is to return the following

| Address | Query Count | Zero Click Queries |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcdomain.com/abc-keyword | 7 | 3 |
| abcdomain.com/kite-flying | 5 | 4 |